# newsletter subscription export error Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, newsletter

I have more than 6000 records of subscription user I am using the Magento core module for that
while exporting all the records my screen shows [https://prnt.sc/unj950]

can anyone help me what's the issue?

**NOTE: ITS MAGENTO CORE MODULE NO OVERRIDE OR ANY EXTENSION INSTALLED **

Comment: does it work with batch export like 20000 records at once ?

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal It was my typing mistake I have approx 6000 records and it works up to 100 records at once I wanted to export all at once